# Synaptic Manager does not display Descriptions of Packages

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

I have always used Synaptic, since upgrading to 16 it now longer displays any information in the right side field: no package names, no descriptions, no installed versions, nothing?
I have changed the searches by Section, Status, Origin, etc...,
There are no Search Filters set,
The status bar on the bottom Does List the number of packages, number installed, and such,
However, even if I select "Installed" there is no displayed information - simply a grayed-out *"No Package Selected"*
In Preferences I have both checked / un-checked "Show Packages In The Main Window" with no result.

Any Suggestions?
And Thank You for Your Time!

Info: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3520 @ 2.16GHz × 4 on a Lenovo Yoga 2 / 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reset your Synaptic software preferences by renaming or deleting the folder `/root/.synaptic`.

1. To do so, you will to run the following command (if you are using Nautilus, edited as suggested by pomsky on 25 Oct):

   ```
   sudo -H nautilus
   ```
2. Browse to the `/root` folder where you will see the `.synaptic` sub-folder.
3. Rename or delete the `/root/.synaptic` folder.
4. Exit Nautilus
5. Restart Synaptic and you can now see the details displayed in the right hand panel.

NOTE: Renaming/ deleting the `/root/.synaptic` folder will reset all your Synaptic software preferences. You will need to reconfigure Synaptic.

Comment: [You should never run GUI applications like Nautilus with normal sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications), use `sudo -H nautilus` instead.

Answer (score 0):

not an expert, although since no one answered it, here -- I remember reading that Synaptic and either apt or another popular package aren't compatible, and that leaves the configuration inconsistent, in case it gives you a clue.

Look up `apt`.  Clean up the lists, and populate them afresh. I wish I could say more than you would find on the web better, *except* that if all that fails to help, look up `dpkg`.

There are good answers around. If you don't find them, please comment and I will reread the topic.

[Thanks for the feedback, editors.]

Comment: Thanks. Any further suggestions?